# Product Structured Data Bug in Woocommerce 3.5

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, structured-data

Using woocommerce 3.5 & wordpress 5, Some days before i noticed that google is not showing rich snippets for my products when i test a product URL at google structured data testing tool, product meta was disappeared.

product structured data is visible in Breadcrumb list. how i can show my product data separately, Please help here is my store URL https://techcart.pk
[image: product data]

Comment: You have to include a minimal example of the markup in the question (as code, not as image). Judging from the few parts the image shows, I would guess [this is the same issue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/119077/17633).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that the Product and final breadcrumb item share the same "@id". This means they are considered to be the same entity, so they get merged.

They are both using an "@id" that represents the page they are on. So in a way they are also sharing the "@id" of the WebPage.

I'd recommend changing their "@id" to something unique. A common solution is to add a # value to the end if the "@id". e.g.

https ://example.com/product12345#Product

That indicates that it is a Product entity on the page.